# What is DiscardableAttribute used for?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, clr, rotor

I can not find the practical use of `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DiscardableAttribute`, even for a prototype compiler. Any insight? Thanks.

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.discardableattribute.aspx) explains a possible use in the remarks section.

Answer (score 6):

To give a more specific example than what the documentation says - you could have a language that supports inlining of static method calls that are marked using some special modifier (from a static class):

```
static class Bar {
  static inline void Foo(int a) { // Note fictional 'inline' modifier
    return a + 10;
  }
}
```

If you have a class like this, it isn't really referenced by any other piece of your code. When you write:

```
int y = Bar.Foo(x);
```

The compiler compiles it as:

```
int y = x + 10;
```

You need to keep the definition of `Bar` in the compiled code, because if you reference the assembly from some other project, you want to see it (and when you then call the `Foo` method, the compiler will just take compiled IL from that assembly).

However, the class `Bar` would never be used at runtime (it is there just to keep the code, but not to actually execute it). I imagine you could mark it as `Discardable` and the JIT could possibly skip it when generating native code for your assembly (because the class will never be used).

Comment: Many thanks, to be honest I was hopping the Jitter could "inline" the following helper class: [Discardable] class AtomicRead : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ReaderWriterLock _lock;

        internal AtomicRead(ReaderWriterLock @lock)
        {
            _lock = @lock;
            _lock.AcquireReaderLock(Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            _lock.ReleaseReaderLock();
        }
    } - OMG > How do I do <Enter> for this editor?! :S